# JQuery Mobile weird behaviour after manual refresh

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

On jQuery mobile app I have some weird bugs which happens after a manual refresh in this page. Hard to explain though..for example this page works correct but **if** I refresh the page then when I go to another page and return back to this page(all separate html files)

```
 $("#accountlist").html(myHtml);
```

does not set the html and I get an empty list but I know "myhtml" has the correct data, **and then** if I go another page **again** and return back **then** html sets correctly.

Any Ideas?

```
<body>

<div class="account" id="accountpage" data-role="page">
    <script>


    $(document).off('pageshow', '#accountpage').on('pageshow', '#accountpage', function() {

        $(document).off('click', '#backbuttonaccount').on('click', '#backbuttonaccount', function(){
            $.mobile.changePage("menu.html", {
                reloadPage: false,
                transition: "flip",
                reverse: true
            });
        });

      $("#accountlist").html("myHtml");
    });

</script>


    <div class="container" id="accountcontanier" data-role="content">
              <ul id="accountlist"> 

              </ul>

    </div>
```

When I debug by using this right after I set it;

```
 console.log($("#accountlist").text())
```

I can always see correct value.

I also tried this kind of stuff but none of them helped

```
 $("#accountlist").listview('refresh');
```

Comment: Do you also have an object with an id accountlist on some other page?

Comment: @Gajotres no I dont have

Comment: Are you sure that #accountlist listviw and its future myHtml content exist first time you return to the page after the refresh?

Comment: @Gajotres using console.log($("#accountlist").text()) I can see correct value right after I set it.

Comment: Then you can see that content is added through console.log but it can't be seen?

Comment: Can you try something. Execute this line: $("#accountlist").listview('refresh'); after this line $("#accountlist").html("myHtml"); Also take a look for any error in console during the execution.

Comment: @Gajotres I tried that actually and got "Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'"

Comment: Excellent, try this one: $("#accountlist").listview().listview('refresh');

Comment: @Gajotres nope..it also broke my style

Comment: Strange, lets try few other things. Instead of listview('refresh') try these to lines (first one then another): $('#accountpage').trigger('create'); and if that one is not working try this one: $('#accountpage').trigger('pagecreate');

Comment: @Gajotres thanks!..but still no effect :)

Comment: Lets go further. Is #accountlist content the same after first and second return to the page?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27878/discussion-between-spring-and-gajotres)

Comment: @Gajotres please see my answer, fixed the stupid bug in a strange way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after 2 days of struggle I fixed the stupid bug, instead of setting the ul id, I added a class id and set it..and somehow it worked!

```
   <ul class="account" id="accountlist"> 

          </ul>
```

and then set it.

```
$('.account').html(myHtml);
```

Though I still appreciate if anyone can explain me why this worked and not the ul id.